# What is the difference between instantiating and loading a class in Java?

Tags: java, object-oriented, jvm

In Java world, there are some scenarios where I see developers used to load the class rather than instantiation. What is the difference between instantiating and loading a class?

Comment: I think this would have suited better on StackOverflow.

Comment: Please see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html where this is explained clearly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order for a class to be instantiated it has to be loaded by the classloader...in many cases this is the first time the class has been just-in-time compiled. If you access a static variable on a class, it has to be loaded. If you want to reflect on a class it has to be loaded. There are many circumstances where you might just load a class rather than instantiate.

Also the static initializer(s) for a class fire the first time the class is loaded (and before anything else). If you have an explicit static intializer you can use it to perform a global initialization if need be.

Comment: Can you please mention certain circumstances where class will only be loaded and not initialised?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is what you mean, but a [classloader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) actually locates the definition for a class and makes it available for use by the JVM.  Then, you can instantiate an instance of it.

Comment: ya why use a classloader rather than creating a instance of the class .....

Comment: You must have a class loaded before you can instantiate it.  They are not alternatives to each other.  What examples are you seeing where this is the case?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, "class loading" refers to loading, and initializing the class definitions -  meaning loading the bytecode from the class file, creating the Class class, running the static initializers, etc.

Once a class is loaded, and initialized, then it would be possible to instantiate an instance of the class -- ie. create an object of that class type.

Comment: Please do not try to add unnecessary (and potentially spammy) links to your answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Instantiating** a class is when you create an instance of that class at runtime. Though I think what you're referring to could be class **initialization**? Just in case, class initialization occurs when any of the following happens:

*1) an Instance of class is created using either new() keyword or using reflection using class.forName(), which may throw ClassNotFoundException in Java.*

*2) a static method of Class is invoked.*

*3) a static field of Class is assigned.*

*4) a static field of class is used which is not a constant variable.*

*5) if Class is a top level class and an assert statement lexically nested within class is executed.*

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/07/when-class-loading-initialization-java-example.html

Class loading is when the JVM pulls the class from its package and loads it into the runtime environment to be used at runtime. The **class loader** is responsible for this process.